# How to filter a field using a regex containing characters and digits in AWS Cloudwatch?

Tags: aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Assuming the log stream contains a message like `hello something 1234`

The following cloudwatch insights query doesn't return any results.

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /something 1234/
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 100
```

However, using them separately returns results.

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /1234/
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 100
```

Or

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /something/
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 100
```

I'm unable to understand why the regex isn't working as expected

Comment: Try `/something\s1234/`. The whitespace character might be something other than `' '`

Comment: It's weird. Didn't return any results with `\s`. 


However, it actually returned a result with the regex `/something  1234/` (two spaces). But, the message has exactly one single space.


Using `/something\s\s1234/` didn't work either.

Comment: Small edit to the above - `/something\s\s1234/` works.

Comment: 1. What flavor of regex they're using. 2. Different whitespace characters: using something like: `[\s\t\r\n]*` might work?

Comment: Response to your edit: Make it `/something\s*1234/` in that case.

Comment: Found the issue. Actually, the problem is with how the log group displays the log message in the aws console. The log actually has two spaces. The console displays a single space and upon extending the line it shows the actual two spaces. Understood the issue after checking the log in source code.

Comment: I assumed that there is only a single space as it was displaying in the console.

Answer (score 2):

So, this is not an issue with the insights query itself.

But, with how cloudwatch log group displays log messages. Since, I took the displayed message as the source of truth, ended up with this issue.

This is an issue with how HTML displays consecutive spaces.

Consecutive spaces are collapsed by default within a html tag. In this case they are using a `<span>`.
When we expand the line, they use the css property `white-space` and change the behaviour to not collapse the consecutive spaces.

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop